# Make a one click application in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I have made my Java project(not web project) ready in eclipse.
Now my requirement is to package this project code into some format so that if windows user clicks on it, my Main class's main method should run and then it can do its job as programmed.

I can make a jar but it will not run as the shortcuts do in windows.
For running jar, user has to go to command line.
Kindly let me know what the options available and direct me to those tutorials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Windows, then convert your jar file to exe using java 2 exe wrapper.

For instance: Launch4j: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Runnable Jar file, the user will not have to use the command-line. As long as Java is installed, the user can double click the file and the program starts.

In Eclipse, right-click your project and select `Export...`. In the upcoming dialog select `Runnable jar file` and then select your class containing the main() method.